# Pivot non-timeseries table in grafana

Tags: postgresql, pivot-table, grafana

I have a (postgresql) database table that is a list of views by date, page and user:

```
date,page,user
2023-01-01,home,user1
2023-01-01,home,user2
2023-01-02,foo,user3
2023-01-02,bar,user1
```

I want to create a stacked bar chart that is the count of views grouped by page, and stacked by user.
I *do not* care about the date field (I will use it to filter for the last x days, but I do not need/want it in my chart).

Looking at [this](https://play.grafana.org/d/ktMs4D6Mk/5-bar-charts-and-pie-charts?orgId=1&editPanel=15) example suggests that if my data looked like below, everything would "Just Work":

```
page,user1,user2,user3
home,1,1,0
foo,0,0,1
bar,0,1,0
```

Dynamic pivot tables appear to be a [nightmare](https://postgresql.verite.pro/blog/2018/06/19/crosstab-pivot.html#how-to-do-a-dynamic-pivot) in postgresql (and I think I can only run a single statement within grafana to get my data).

I therefore wanted to use the internal 'Transform' functionality of grafana. I should be able to group my table by page and user, and then use the [rows to fields](https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/panels-visualizations/query-transform-data/transform-data/#labels-to-fields) transformation.

HOWEVER. I'm failing miserably. The rows to fields transformation drops the "page" column so all I get is:

```
user1,user2,user3,
1,1,0
0,0,1
0,1,0
```

which is useless.

Is this possible? If so, how?